# How to stop local app that was ran with 'npm run dev' command

Tags: npm, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a React app in VSCode that's running on localhost:3000. I can visit the app in the browser. If I try to do ctrl+c in the terminal, an empty line is written but the app is still accessible. I need to close the app for some changes I'm planning to make. What's the best way to do this?